# Is it possible to map a bitmap into a trapezoid

Tags: android, drawing

I have a bitmap. I would like to draw this bitmap into a trapezoid, anchoring the four corners of the original bitmap to the corners of the trapezoid. Is this possible in Android?

Comment: And what is the reason for the -2?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Matrix.setSkew`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setSkew(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)).

```
matrix.setSkew(0.5f, 0.5f, bitmap.getWidth/2, bitmap.getHeight/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Or [`Canvas.drawBitmapMesh`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmapMesh(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20float[],%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint)).

```
canvas.drawBitmapMesh(bitmap, 1, 1, new float[]{
    0.3f, 0,
    0.6f, 0,
    0, 1, 
    1, 1,
}, 0, null, 0, null);
```

You'll need to experiment with the float[] in and the values for skew.

Comment: The first solution would be more a parallelogram. drawBitmapMesh looks promising for him though.

Comment: Whoops, yeah, I usually use graphics.Camera for this kind of thing, but that's a whole other can of worms.